# Can not make a task scheduling for a batch file containing a .py file to start in Windows 10

Tags: python

I have the following batch file

```
SET logfile="C:\Reports\logbatch.log"
@echo off
@echo Starting Script at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe" 
"C:\Users\mypc\source\repos\WebS\WebS\Start_Master.py"
@echo finished at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
pause
```

The **Start_Master.py** contains several other scripts located in the same folder with Start_Master.py

The batch file works If I run it manually.

When I create a task and the task runs automatically or manually I get that
it cannot open the files

```
python: can't open the file 'script1.py' No such file or directory
python: can't open the file 'script2.py' No such file or directory
python: can't open the file 'script3.py' No such file or directory
```

Comment: but what is inside of Start_Master.py? how exactly paths are set for script1/2/3.py?

Comment: scripts1/2/3 are located in the same folder with batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY:**

```
SET logfile="C:\Reports\logbatch.log"
@echo off
@echo Starting Script at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
cd "C:\Users\mypc\source\repos\WebS\WebS\"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe" 
"C:\Users\mypc\source\repos\WebS\WebS\Start_Master.py"
@echo finished at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
pause
```

Try changing your **CWD** (current working directory), to the directory in which **Start_Master.py** exists

Comment: It is working but why I need to pass first the directory?

Comment: It is because in batch script, if the CWD is not the same as your python file location, then upon automatic execution of the file, module not exists errors arise. Because your file may be using abstract paths to reference its neighbor python files (or modules), and since the CWD is not the same as your python file location, then abstract paths won't work as full path's are then required

Comment: You can change `C:\Users\mypc\source\repos\WebS\WebS\Start_Master.py` into `Start_Master.py` now, since you're already in the correct directory. And the lines with python.exe and the python file should be combined into one line.

Comment: I didn't wanted to optimize the code, as it may become a little overwhelming for the OP to understand so may changes at the same time, so I just did a single (necessary) change which was required.